# Python : Cant append values to a list in a While Loop

Tags: python, list, append

I extract some values from Images, now I need to gather all the extracted items from the Image and append them to a List and return them in the end.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_roles_text():
    start = [107, 338, 215, 21]
    while(True):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(start[0], start[1], start[2], start[3]))
        text = tess.image_to_string(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
        all_roles = list()
        print(text)
        all_roles.append(text)
        print(text)
        start = [start[0], start[1] + start[3], start[2], start[3]]
        if text == '':
            print(all_roles)
            break
            return all_roles

    print(all_roles)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You re-create the list anew on each iteration of the string. Created it before the loop.

Also, your `return` is never reached, as there is a `break` in the line before it. See fixes, below, with a few style fixes annotated in comments.

```
def get_roles_text():
    all_roles = [] # Move it up here. Also, [] is more idiomatic than list()
    start = [107, 338, 215, 21]
    while True: # No need for parens
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(start[0], start[1], start[2], start[3]))
        # Leave out all those print() statements until you need them
        text = tess.image_to_string(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
        if not text: # not text is an idiomatic way to say text == ''
            return all_roles
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are resetting the list in every iteration of the loop, you should initialize the list outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Init your list outside `while` loop:

```
def get_roles_text():
    start = [107, 338, 215, 21]
    all_roles = []
    while(True):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(start[0], start[1], start[2], start[3]))
        text = tess.image_to_string(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
        print(text)
        all_roles.append(text)
        print(text)
        start = [start[0], start[1] + start[3], start[2], start[3]]
        if text == '':
            print(all_roles)
            break
            return all_roles

    print(all_roles)
```